# How to list values from MySQL table in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I would have posted some code, however I completely have no idea where to start!

So I want my employees to use my VB application to request holiday (that bit is done). But now I want them to see all the holidays they have requested in a list.

They each have their own account and their username is present on the holiday table in the database.

It must be able to show all holidays they have booked and not just one, preference is in a list form. I'd also like to exclude 1 column from showing.

Is this possible?

I really appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Use a `DataGridView` and a query like `SELECT h.UserName, h.Date, ... FROM dbo.Holiday d ORDER BY  h.UserName, h.Date` to fill a `DataTable` with a `MySqlDataAdapter` and use that as `DataSource` for a `BindingSource` that is the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`.